# Hibernate could not resolve property for capitalized value name

Tags: hibernate

I have two classes:

```
public class User {

    private int id;
    private String Name;
    private Set<Contact> Contacts = new HashSet<Contact>();

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    ...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "owner", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public Set<Contact> getContacts() {
        return
    }
}
```

and

```
public class Contact {

    private int id;
    private String nick;
    private int age;
    private User owner;

    ...

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "UserId")
    public User getOwner() {
        return owner;
    }
}
```

When I call:

```
session.createCriteria(Contact.class).add(Restrictions.eq("owner.id", 2)).list();
```

everything is fine, but if I change User's "id" property name to "Id" the code compile but:

```
session.createCriteria(Contact.class).add(Restrictions.eq("owner.Id", 2)).list();
```

will throw me the "could not resolve property owner.Id" exception.

I know that in Java I should start a variable name with a lowercase, but I just want to know why Hibernate behave in this way.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Because the strings you add in any Criteria, Restriction, or HQL are not really a script language (such as SQL). Hibernate has a sophisticated mechanism which will make reflection calls based on your inputs.

So, by the end of the day if you have:

```
session.createCriteria(Contact.class).add(Restrictions.eq("owner.Id", 2)).list();
```

Hibernate will indeed create a object for `Contact` class, which will have a object called `owner` and call `Id` (case sensitive) via `getId()` since you added the annotation on the method.

Briefly speaking that is the reason why...